# SQL Server : how to get only latest(deepest) nodes of the tree

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree

If node has child element then not to select this node otherwise return this node:

This is my query which returns all rows with level column:

```
 WITH AnalysisTree(Oid, 
              Name, 
              Parent, 
              Level)
 AS (SELECT a.Oid, 
            a.Name, 
            a.ParentAnalysis Parent, 
            0 AS Level
     FROM Analysis a
     WHERE a.GCRecord IS NULL
           AND a.ParentAnalysis IS NULL
     UNION ALL
     SELECT a2.Oid, 
            a2.Name, 
            a2.ParentAnalysis Parent, 
            AnalysisTree.level + 1 level
     FROM Analysis a2
          INNER JOIN AnalysisTree ON AnalysisTree.Oid = a2.ParentAnalysis
     WHERE a2.GCRecord IS NULL)
 SELECT *
 FROM AnalysisTree atr;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * 
from AnalysisTree 
where Oid not in (select ParentAnalysis from Analysis where ParentAnalysis is not null)
```

Comment: Thanks, i don't need cte query at all :)

Comment: might be better with if exists() ...?

Comment: I changed my query as below:       
SELECT *
FROM Analysis a
WHERE a.GCRecord IS NOT NULL
      AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT ParentAnalysis
    FROM Analysis
    WHERE ParentAnalysis = a.Oid);